# dynamic findcontrol in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to make this work in javascript with dynamic `addressType`,

```
var addressType = "foo";

document.getElementById('<%= this.FindControl("'" + addressType + "'").ClientID%>').value = val;
```

Comment: You are mixing client side and server side code. That's impossible. If you want - elaborate more about your use case so that we could suggest you a way of implementing it

Comment: I am trying to get javascript manupulated value of hidden inputs onclick of a linkbutton. component is usercontrol I couldn't reach from Request.Forms some how.

Comment: what you are suggesting is static not dynamic, and I solved the problem you can find in asnwers. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign a `CssClass` property to the element. For example:

```
<asp:SomeElement CssClass="someclass">

document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0].value;
```

Comment: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' does not have a public property named 'class'. or CssClass :(

Comment: It has a `ClientIDMode` you set to `Static`. The same principles applies: `document.getElementById('idname').value`. You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

```
var addressType = "foo";

document.getElementById('<%= this.ClientID +"_"%>' + addressType).value = val;
```